# I follow a spring boot tutorial and I face a problem about internationalization

Tags: spring, spring-boot

the default response should be good morning but the server respond with bonjour as default response
( I am beginner about asking questions in Stackoverflow and I hope you inderstand the problem )

### this is the two beans I added in the main class :##

```
@Bean
    public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
        SessionLocaleResolver localeResolver = new SessionLocaleResolver();
        localeResolver.setDefaultLocale(Locale.US);
        return localeResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource(){
        ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("messages");
        return messageSource;
    }
```

### this the code of message.properties :

```
good.morning.message=good morning
```

### this the code of message_fr.properties :

```
 good.morning.message=bonjour
```

### this is the code of the get mapping method :

```
    @GetMapping("/helloInter")
    public  String hello(@RequestHeader(name ="Accept-Language",required = false) Locale locale){
        return messageSource.getMessage("good.morning.message",null,locale);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the Accept-Language header in your controller to define the locale. Please check that you are not including fr in the header since that will override the default US locale you are setting in the SessionLocaleResolver.

Comment: I check it and fr value is not included

Comment: How are you testing the API? Using some tool like Postman or directly from the browser?